# simplexml_load_file(): Failed to enable crypto

Tags: php, windows, ssl, iis

Recently upgraded our IIS and PHP (5.6.3) is now giving me this error.

A lot of the fixes around this seem to point towards changing curl options but we are using simplexml_load_file() all across the project, it seems like it would be a  pain to rewrite all our instances using curl requests. Is there a more universal solution to this problem?

Is there something I could change in openssl.cnf or in php.ini to disable this extra security. There is no feasible way for this connection to not be loading files off our own server so I don't mind disabling certificate checking (which appears to be the cause of the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For Ubuntu
>
> you should have to install openssl for your server let me give you steps.
>
> 1 `brew install openssl`

This installs the openssl certificates to `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`, so we can now use the new PHP 5.6 INI setting `openssl.cafile` to tell PHP where to find the certificates.

Adding

```
openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

to Zend Server’s `php.ini` solved the problem and I can now use composer once again!

For more details please [click here](https://akrabat.com/ssl-certificate-verification-on-php-5-6/).

> For Windows Follow this steps
> Another problem under Windows is that you don't have access to the certificates. So put the root certificates directly to curl.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Here you can download the root certificates.

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, **DIR** . "/certs/cacert.pem");
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

Then you can use the:

> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

option with:

> true

otherwise you get an error.

Comment: We're using Windows, not OSX and I believe openssl is already instealled, I'm going to try add that line to the PHP ini file if i can find the cert.pem

Comment: Sadly this hasn't worked I downloaded OpenSSL for windows which didn't come with a cert.pem so I got hold of the cacert.pem manually and placed it in the correct location alongside my installation of OpenSSL checked `openssl_get_cert_locations()` to make sure it was the same location and it was but sadly I'm still getting the same error after an IIS restart

Comment: @Richie Please check my post i update some content for windows hopefully it will work..